# Converting dict values from unicode to utf-8 (or ascii) within csv dictwriter

Tags: python, csv, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to print some data to a csv file but unicode is killing my vibe.

My data is in dictionary format - a snippet here:

```
 {'category': u'Best food blog written by a linguist\xa0', 'runners_up': [], 'winner': [u'shesimmers.com'], 'category_url': 'http://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-food-blog-written-by-a-linguist/BestOf?oid=4101663'}
```

and this the segment of my code where I'm employing the DictWriter method.

```
    data = utf_8_encoder(data)
    with open('best_food_n_drink.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        categories = ['category', 'category_url', 'winner', 'runners_up']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter =',', fieldnames=categories)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

utf_8_encoder is from a function I defined earlier:

```
  def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        line.encode('utf-8')
    return unicode_csv_data
```

I keep getting error messages like `'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'`. I've tried doing something along the lines of forgoing the encoder function and substituting `row.values().encode('utf-8')` in the for loop at the bottom, but that just tells me `list object has no attribute 'encode'.

I've tried substituting `('utf-8')` with `('ascii', 'ignore')` as well but just can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to encode a string, not a list, or a dictionary.

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 2.7.6.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what format you expect the output in but this will encode your strings:

```
def map_to(d):
    # iterate over the key/values pairings
    for k, v in d.items():
        # if v is a list join and encode else just encode as it is a string
        d[k] = ",".join(v).encode("utf-8") if isinstance(v, list) else v.encode("utf-8")



map_to(data)

with open('best_food_n_drink.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    categories = ['category', 'category_url', 'winner', 'runners_up']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=categories)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)
```

This will output something like the following but with your mixture of strings and lists I don't really know what it should end up like:

```
category,category_url,winner,runners_up
Best food blog written by a linguist ,http://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-food-blog-written-by-a-linguist/BestOf?oid=4101663,shesimmers.com,
```

Now we have discovered you actually have a list if dicts we need to iterate over the list but the logic is still the same, we just run the function on each dict in the loop:

```
data = [{'category': u"Best restaurant that's been around forever and is still worth the trip\xa0", 'runners_up': [u'Frontera Grill', u'Chicago Diner ', u'Sabatino\u2019s', u'Twin Anchors'], 'winner': [u'Lula Cafe'], 'category_url': 'http://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/BestOf?category=1979894&year=2011'},
{'category': u'Best bang for your buck\xa0', 'runners_up': [u'Frasca Pizzeria & Wine Bar', u'Chutney Joe\u2019s', u'"My boyfriend!"'], 'winner': [u'Big Star', u'Sultan\u2019s Market']}]

def map_to(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = ",".join(v).encode("utf-8") if isinstance(v, list) else v.encode("utf-8")

with open('best_food_n_drink.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    categories = ['category', 'category_url', 'winner', 'runners_up']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=categories)
    writer.writeheader()
    # get each dict from the list
    for d in data:
        # run the encode func
        map_to(d)
        writer.writerow(d)
```

I presume `'category_url'` actually exists in the second dict.

To catch the None's and avoid encoding errors add a line to the func:

```
def map_to(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        # catch None's
        if v is not None:
            d[k] = " ".join(v).encode("utf-8") if isinstance(v, list) else v.encode("utf-8")
```

Depending on what you plan on doing with the data storing the data as `json` might be useful:

```
import  json
with open('best_food_n_drink.js', 'w') as js:
    json.dump(data,js)
```

Then to get the list if data:

```
import  json
with open('best_food_n_drink.json') as js:
    data = json.load(js)
```

Comment: is this particular format of csv output how you would do it/recommend? or is there a way to make it more readable/presentable in your opinion?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, why are some values in lists?

Comment: no, just wondering. so what would you say was the root issue in the original code? when I just turned the dict into a string, 

`def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        return ':'.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in line.items())`

it didn't work either, saying:
`'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128)'

Comment: also shouldn't we iterate over each item in the dict for writer.writerows()?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce,  the problem with your function in your question is that you return after the first line so you only encode one key./string and don't actually change the actual objects in the dict at all so you are still passing the data dict as is

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, no, that will split the keys into single characters i.e `'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'g', 'o', 'r', 'y'` and would cause an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78129/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

With python 3.4 using :

```
io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

instead of

```
open(filename, 'w')
```

solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution is to create comprehensive methods that will check for further types beyond just `unicode` and `list`, I know in the original questions isn't but anyone can get here trying to convert a complex `dict` (with inner dicts, lists...), so here is my contribution:

```
def array_to_utf(a):
    autf = []
    i = 0
    for v in a:
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            autf.append(v.encode('utf-8'))
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            autf.append(dict_to_utf(v))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            autf.append(array_to_utf(v))
        else:
            autf.append(v)
    return autf

def dict_to_utf(d):
    dutf = {}
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            dutf[k] = v.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            dutf[k] = array_to_utf(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            dutf[k] = dict_to_utf(v)
        else:
            dutf[k] = v
    return dutf

test = {1: u'1', 2: '2', 3: {'x': u'x', 'y': 'y'}, 4: [u'ara', 's', 123], 5: 123}

print(dict_to_utf(a))
# {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: {'y': 'y', 'x': 'x'}, 4: ['ara', 's', 123], 5: 123}
```

Both methods are recursive on their own and between each other.